# Which Ubuntu packages are considered genuine?

Tags: 11.04, installation, bug-reporting

I tried to report a bug issue on update manager but got the following error:

> Your problem cannot be reported. This
>   is not a genuine Ubuntu package.

Isn't Ubuntu open source?

Answer (score 8):

Genuine ubuntu package are all the packages that you can install through Ubuntu Software Center. Packages that are installed from third party repositories (PPA) are not considered genuine. 
This mechanism is just to distinguish bug reports of packages that are officially available in Ubuntu repositories from the ones that the end-user has installed from an unknown source.

Let's take an example:

If you download and install, lets say virtual box from oracle's website and this piece of software for some reason crashes, the bug report that may be generated can not be reported to launchpad because it is from an unknown source. But if you install virtualbox from software center then any crash that produces bug report can be uploaded to Launchpad

Comment: And again ANOTHER thing I did not know (Apart from the other 2 million I still do not know)

Answer (score 0):

@Munna, There may be bug-reporting capability at the source from where you downloaded the package. Check for that.. You may be able to report your bug there. Opensource projects usually have a location for bug reporting. So even though your package is third-party(or unofficial), the bugs can be reported elsewhere.